# How realistic is parachute jumping from Caesars Palace in Hangover?

Tags: realism, the-hangover-3

In Hangover III Leslie Chow jumps off Caesars Palace to escape capture by Phil.

Parachute jumps are to be made from plane at sufficient altitude.

A quick Google search gave up heights like 600 to 1200 and 700 feet.

So how realistic is jumping and landing safely from height of a building like Caesars Palace which is 435 feet.

Comment: Google *parachute jump height minimum*

Comment: @user7294900: I did. And that's why asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's plausible.

Although your question touches upon figures from 600 feet, those generally cover the time for a normal parachute to open when falling out of a plane.

In the case of the video posted (I've not seen the film), Chow appears to be BASE jumping. This involves packing the parachute to allow it to open sooner. In these cases, it's possible to fall and land safely within 100 feet or so:

He's obviously not upright when he falls, so we need to allow a little time for this. From http://www.greenharbor.com/fffolder/questions.html:

> If a human were to jump from 100 feet about ground level, it would take about 2.5 seconds before they hit the ground.

2.5 seconds should be enough for him to spin around, deploy the parachute, slow his descent to a safe speed, and still have 235 feet to play with. With enough warm air currents (such as those generated by air conditioning units in the middle of a desert), there should be no reason why he can't then glide onwards.

Comment: Agreed that 435 feet is plenty of altitude for a BASE jump, although the length of his glide under the deployed parachute is pure fantasy. BASE jumping parachutes, unlike say paragliding canopies, are not nearly aerodynamically efficient enough to stay aloft with the help of thermal currents - they are designed to come down, and except in rare and extreme atmospheric conditions he'd have been on the ground within a few seconds.